# Json response only value but key + value needed

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

The following PHP code translates only the values but I also need the key to each value:

How it should be (desired output):

```
[{"ID":"1","styleNo":"1","styleName":"Casual","placeholder":"Left Initial","type":"text","maxlength":"1","size":"small","position":"1"},{"ID":"2","styleNo":"1","styleName":"Casual","placeholder":"Right Initial","type":"text","maxlength":"1","size":"small","position":"2"},{"ID":"3","styleNo":"1","styleName":"Casual","placeholder":"Center Initial","type":"text","maxlength":"1","size":"small","position":"3"}]
```

How it actually is (I don´t know wether the different brackets matter?):

```
[["1","1","Casual","Left Initial","text","1","small","1"],["2","1","Casual","Right Initial","text","1","small","2"],["3","1","Casual","Center Initial","text","1","small","3"]]

<?php
$style = $_GET['style'];
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', '');
define('DBNAME', 'inscribe');

$db = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DBNAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s<br/>", mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM inputs WHERE styleNo = '".$style."'";
$result_db = $db->query($sql);
$all_result = $result_db->fetch_all();
echo json_encode($all_result);
$db->close();
?>
```

Comment: so whats the problem? what does `$all_result` look like after encoded?

Comment: It looks like the "How it actually is" part above, only printing the values but not the Keys like ID, styleNo, styleName...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to explicitly set the mysql fetch flag to `MYSQLI_ASSOC` in `fetch_all()` since its default is `MYSQLI_NUM` which returns numerical indices instead of associative.

Example:

```
$all_result = $result_db->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($all_result);
```

Sidenote: Either escape the input or use prepared statements:

```
$style = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['style']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inputs WHERE styleNo = '$style' ";
$result_db = $db->query($sql);
$all_result = $result_db->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($all_result);
```

Or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inputs WHERE styleNo = ?";
$select = $db->prepare($sql);
$select->bind_param('s', $_GET['input']);
$select->execute();
$result = $select->get_result();
$all_result = $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($all_result);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's doing what it should. sql queries return rows of results so thats what it's giving you. a quick fix would be

```
$tmp = array();
$keys = array("ID", "styleNo", "placeholder", "type", "maxlength", "size", "position");
foreach($all_result as $row){
     $tmp[] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}

echo json_encode($tmp);
```

if your select changes this may break.